# Action Mailer error: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have a Rails application which uses a form to collect message details and emails the message to my gmail/yahoo account.

I have added this to setup_mail.rb in config/initializers:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {  
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",  
      :port                 => 587,  
      :user_name            => "my_user",
      :password             => "my_pass", 
      :authentication       => "plain",  
      :enable_starttls_auto => true  
  }
```

and use the controller like so for the POST route:

```
def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])

    if @message.valid?
      NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver!
      redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Message was successfully sent.")
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Please fill all fields."
      redirect_to('#')
    end
end
```

The Message Parameters are accepted from the form cleanly like so:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4xgV0umvaTPzYxd18qdJq/GT7QCdXjrPTGR7D9R3AC4=", "message"=>{"name"=>"Deepak", "email"=>"deepakm.ccx@gmail.com", "subject"=>"Hi", "body"=>"Hi"}, "commit"=>"Send"}
```

No matter if I use Yahoo credentials or Gmail Credentials in the setup, I keep getting the same error message. I commented all the settings in ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings and still get this issue. This leads me to believe the issue could be related to something else outside this code but I have no clue whatsoever.

-Deepak

Comment: did you allow external connections to send emails in your google account preferences?

Comment: I don't see settings for outgoing mails. I've enabled the IMAP settings on gmail but still the same error. Is this correct? Both outgoing and incoming mails are from my gmail ID.

Comment: when i had same problem and logged in to google mail i saw notification string at the top of the page that someone wants to send emails from my account externally. and there was a button - to allow this action (or something like that) also, check if user name ends with `@gmail.com`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I dont see any notifications from gmail. In fact I commented out all the SMTP settings including the address, user name and password and still see the same error msg  'User Name and Password are not accepted'. Seems like the mail command is creating an SMTP channel but it may not be reaching the gmail server.

Answer (score 0):

You mention your code is in `config/initializers` - we have `ActionMailer` working, and it sends through Gmail, except we put this into our `config/environments/developer.rb` file:

```
  #Send Email In Development (Use Gmail's Servers)
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port                 => 587,
      :domain               => "*****.co.uk",
      :user_name            => "******@gmail.com",
      :password             => "******",
      :authentication       => :plain,
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
      :host => "localhost:3000"
  }
```

Maybe you could try copy-and-pasting the above code?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried these settings, without adding a the domain key since I'm not using google apps, and enabling IMAP. I'm receiving the same message: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Are there any puts I can do to debug where this error is coming from?

Comment: Are you sure you can send with IMAP? I'm sure it's just for retrieval. Maybe that's a problem?

Comment: According to the doc, IMAP must be enabled to read messages on external clients and SMTP is used to send messages from External Clients. I think IMAP need not be enabled for ActionMailer to work. https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?rd=1#ts=1665018,1665144 . Could it be an issue with firewall?

Comment: Yes - it seems you want to send messages by your rails app? In that case, you need to use the SMTP protocol to send the message, which will then deliver to your inbox via IMAP

Answer (score 0):

While I am still unable to send emails via ActionMailer still, I thought I would post an alternative.

https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail

Works well and is easier because you dont need to use any config files.

Thanks.